# Place pie charts on nodes of force directed layout graph in D3

Tags: graph, d3.js, pie-chart, force-layout

I would like to place pie charts on the node of a D3 force directed layout graph using D3.js. This is a common visualization in population genetics, see for example http://mathildasanthropologyblog.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/as3.jpg

[image]

I've started with a very basic graph plot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

graph = { "nodes":[{"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 1}, 
                                    {"group": 2, "value": 2}, 
                                    {"group": 3, "value": 3}]},
                   {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 2}, 
                                    {"group": 2, "value": 2}, 
                                    {"group": 3, "value": 2}]}],
          "links":[{"source": 0, "target": 1, "length": 500, "width": 1}]
        }

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = 10,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .size([width, height]);

force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .call(force.drag);

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to replace the circle nodes with pie charts, the pie charts all end up stacked in the corner of the plot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

graph = { "nodes":[{"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 1}, 
                                    {"group": 2, "value": 2}, 
                                    {"group": 3, "value": 3}]},
                   {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 2}, 
                                    {"group": 2, "value": 2}, 
                                    {"group": 3, "value": 2}]}],
          "links":[{"source": 0, "target": 1, "length": 500, "width": 1}]
        }

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = 10,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .size([width, height]);

force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node");

node.selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) {return pie(d.proportions); })
 .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });;

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any assistance would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be the last statement in your force-on-tick callback:

```
node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

SVG paths have no such x/y attributes.  Try translating the path instead:

```
node.attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; });
```

Answer (score 2):

The code as above wasn't working, the snippet below displays both pie charts, in the right location, with edges visible and with pie chart colors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <style>

        .node {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .link {
            stroke: #808080;
            stroke-opacity: .6;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    graph = { "nodes":[
                    {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 1},
                                     {"group": 2, "value": 2},
                                     {"group": 3, "value": 3}]},
                    {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 2},
                                     {"group": 2, "value": 2},
                                     {"group": 3, "value": 2}]}],
              "links":[{"source": 0, "target": 1, "length": 500, "width": 1}]
    }

    var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = 25,
    color = d3.scale.category10();

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius)
        .innerRadius(0);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(4 * radius)
        .size([width, height]);

    force.nodes(graph.nodes)
         .links(graph.links)
         .start();

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");

    node.selectAll("path")
        .data(function(d, i) {return pie(d.proportions); })
        .enter()
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });;

    force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```