# How to instanciate custom pie charts as node of a D3 force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, progress-bar, force-layout

I am trying to put together a force directed graph in which I would like some of the nodes to be progress bars. I have put together a circular progress bar using a donut pie chart but now I am struggling to see how to instantiate several of these pie chart and have them in place of node.

Circular progress bar: http://jsfiddle.net/qwTFN/

[image]

I have already found a related question [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju5Ib.gif) and tweaked some code to put a standard pie chart as node but my problem here is that I want my own custom chart (as per the jsfiddle link)...

```
any ideas appreciated ;)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju5Ib.gif) [Place pie charts on nodes of force directed layout graph in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794055/place-pie-charts-on-nodes-of-force-directed-layout-graph-in-d3/18176445#18176445)