# Plot a Network with specified coordinates in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, plot, graph-theory

I was using D3.js to plot a network of pie charts using a force-directed layout using the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794055/place-pie-charts-on-nodes-of-force-directed-layout-graph-in-d3).  Now I would like to plot the network of pies at pre-calculated coordinates and I am unsure how to proceed.  I have added two node attributes (x,y) for plotting, now I need to access them within my javascript.

I would also like to add mouse over labels to my pie charts, so I have added a variable labels, but am unsure about how to access those as well, but if I could get help with the xy coordinates, I bet I could figure out the mouse-over bits.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <style>

        .node {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .link {
            stroke: #808080;
            stroke-opacity: .6;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  graph = { "nodes":[{"proportions": [
{"group":1, "value": 25 },
{"group":2, "value": 0 },
{"group":3, "value": 0 },
{"group":4, "value": 0 }],"x":-315.838,"y":-500},{"proportions": [
{"group":1, "value": 0 },
{"group":2, "value": 25 },
{"group":3, "value": 0 },
{"group":4, "value": 0 }],"x":500,"y":-315.851},{"proportions": [
{"group":1, "value": 0 },
{"group":2, "value": 0 },
{"group":3, "value": 25 },
{"group":4, "value": 0 }],"x":315.838,"y":500},{"proportions": [
{"group":1, "value": 0 },
{"group":2, "value": 0 },
{"group":3, "value": 0 },
{"group":4, "value": 25 }],"x":-500,"y":315.851}],"links": [{ "source":0, "target":1, "length":900, "width":9},
{ "source":0, "target":3, "length":900, "width":9},
{ "source":1, "target":2, "length":900, "width":9},
{ "source":2, "target":3, "length":900, "width":9}]
} 
var labels = ['mycave1','mycave2','mycave3','mycave4'];
var width = 4000,
    height = 1000,
    radius = 100,
  color = d3.scale.category10();

   var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius)
.innerRadius(0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(4 * radius)
.size([width, height]);

force.nodes(graph.nodes)
.links(graph.links)
.start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node");

node.selectAll("path")
.data(function(d, i) {return pie(d.proportions); })
.enter()
.append("svg:path")
.attr("d", arc)
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });;

force.on("tick", function() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
});
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reposition the entire pie charts if you define each one as a `g` element and use the `transform:translate` attribute. Your code would look something like this:

```
var pies = svg.selectAll('.pie')
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr('transform', function(d){
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    });
```

Here's a fiddle of that in your code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rL6f8h2n/)

Only one node is visible in that because the other nodes have negative x/y attributes and are being translated off the page.

All of the data associated with a node will be visible when you have that node in your selection, while only the data of the individual slice will be visible when you select all of the slices. Also note that `g` elements don't have `x` and `y` attributes, only a `transform` attribute. [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGElement)

Comment: That helps a great deal actually, I fixed the coordinates so that they are all positive, now I simply need to fix the links, it displays a square with the previous force directed links...

Comment: If you want to keep a force directed layout, you can add the same `.attr('transform', ...)` line to your tick function. Right now, the links are starting in the right spot, but then moving based on the force layout, which is updating links but not nodes. http://jsfiddle.net/rL6f8h2n/3/

Comment: I don't want the force-directed layout, how do I get the links to stay in the original place?

Comment: The thing that moves the links is the `force.on('tick')` callback on the force-directed layout. If you take out that method, nothing will move. It's also the only thing that positions the lines right now, so you'll also have to move the `link.attr()` stuff out of that callback.