# How to draw inside graph nodes?

Tags: d3.js

I can use d3 to draw a pie chart or a graph, I can even draw a pie chart within each node of a graph as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794055/place-pie-charts-on-nodes-of-force-directed-layout-graph-in-d3).

Is it possible to create a reusable function that generate the pie chart and attach its result to the each node? That way the pie chart code could be reused, for instance in a gallery of charts.

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

    // draw pie chart
    node.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d, i) {return pie(d.proportions); })
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });;
```

From the above code, I tried the following code which doesn't work

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(drawPie(function(d) { return d.proportions; }));

     function drawPie(d) {
        this.selectAll("path")
        .data(function(d, i) {return pie(d.proportions); })
        .enter()
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });;
     }
```

Comment: If you read the documentation for selection.call you will see that it "Invokes the specified function once, passing in the current selection along with any optional arguments." It passes the selection as the first argument, not the datum. But anyway, you are trying to call `null`, because that is what is returned by `drawPie` and that is the reason your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original idea is much closer than the one recommended in the other answer, you just need to understand how [selection.call](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#call) works.

This is not tested but the general principle is like...

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.call(drawPie);

 function drawPie(selection) {
    this.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d, i) {return pie(d.proportions); })
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });;
 }
```

In reference to your first attempt, if you stop and think about this line...

```
.call(drawPie(function(d) { return d.proportions; }));
```

...it's actually trying to call `null` because that's what is returned by `drawPie`.  It's equivalent to...

```
.call(null);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you all for helping and taking the time to explain my failures. The documentation is great, however for non programmers such as me it still requires complementary help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommendations, here is the modified code which still require some improvements. An error message report that "row 93 undefined is not an object evaluating d.proportions"

```
        graph = { "nodes":[
                           {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 1},
                                            {"group": 2, "value": 2},
                                            {"group": 3, "value": 3}]},
                           {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 2},
                                            {"group": 2, "value": 2},
                                            {"group": 3, "value": 2}]}],
                                            "links":[{"source": 0, "target": 1, "length": 500, "width": 1}]
        }

    var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = 25,
    color = d3.scale.category10();

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(10);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(4 * radius)
    .size([width, height]);

    force.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append(function(d) {return createPie(d);}) // .append(createPie)  --- shorter version
    .attr("class", "node");

    // node.selectAll("path")
    // .data(function(d, i) {return pie(d.proportions); })
    // .enter()
    // .append("svg:path")
    // .attr("d", arc)
    // .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });;

    force.on("tick", function() {
             link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
             .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
             .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
             .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

             node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
             .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
             .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
             });

    function createPie(d) {
        console.log(d);
            var pie = d3.select(document.createElement('svg:g'));
            pie.selectAll('path')
                .data(function(d, i) {return pie(d.proportions); })
                .enter()
                .append("svg:path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });
            return pie.node();
     }
```

Comment: Your original attempt was closer, this is heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append(function(d){return createPie(d);}) // .append(createPie)  --- shorter version
    .attr("class", "node");


function createPie(data) {
    var pie = d3.select(document.createElement('svg:g'));

    pie.selectAll('path')
    ...;

    return pie.node();
}
```

UPDATE:

```
function createPie(d) {
    console.log(d);
        var p = d3.select(document.createElement('svg:g'));
        p.selectAll('path')
            .data(pie(d.proportions))
            .enter()
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.group); });
        return p.node();
 }
```

the previous variable pie needs to be refactored because it overwrites the one in parent scope.

and the data call needs to be fixed as well

Comment: .attr("class", "node");


can be moved inside the function as well

Comment: It's not working, so I'm reporting below the whole modified code, I'd appreciate if you could take a look.